# Authorize.net refund process without credit card number

Tags: authorize.net

How to refund the amount via authorize.net API using c# without credit card number.
I just want to post only transaction id for refund process.
Is that possible in code level?
When i try to refund without credit card number it shows value as "Credit card number is required.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do that. They require the CC number.

Answer (score 1):

Use getTransactionDetails to get the payment object and then use it with the transaction id to issue a refund http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions-refund-a-transaction

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible but in different way.

First get the transaction details from transaction id, then get the credit card and expiration date from that transaction details 
then use this credit card number which will be 4 digits and expiration date(mask date) and setting the transcation id in refund.
It will works fine. 
you can get more details here
http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions-refund-a-transaction